# Escape sequence character in sql query parameter in windows azure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

When querying a string column, if the search parameter has a " ' " in it, the execution fails due to a syntax error. I tried to use an escape sequence character (if thats how its called), but it still does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM OpusOne.Accounts WHERE firstName like '%jose\'%'
```

What would be the correct way to add a quote " ' " to a string parameter ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT * FROM OpusOne.Accounts WHERE firstName like '%jose''%'
```

Escape using another single quote.